# Complicated SELECT statement includes multiple joins not returning desired results

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I am trying to create a SELECT to return information from a couple of tables. I had it working but then received an additional requirement and now I am having trouble figuring out how to get what I want.

I have a table with information on programs that could be included in the report (based on further requirements)...this file is called milestones.
I have another table with projects in it that relate to the programs - if the IDs match
I have a new table that has a manually entered override end date - this is the new requirement. There is a system end date in the milestones table, but if this override date is entered then it takes precedence over the system end date. If an override date has been entered, the exception file will have the same program ID and two dates which match dates in the milestones table.

dates are yyyy-mm-dd formatted

```
Example data:

Milestones:

prgId | startDate  | endDate
------------------------------
  123 | 2014-03-09 | 2014-11-10
  123 | 2014-07-10 | 2014-11-10
  324 | 2014-05-09 | 2014-11-12

exceptions:

prgId | startDate  | overEnd
-------------------------------
  123 | 2014-03-09 | 2014-05-31

projects:

prgId | cust
-------------
  123 | 12121
  123 | 4323
```

what I currently have being returned is:

```
prgId       prjCnt       startDate       endDate     overEnd
123           2          2014-03-09     2014-11-10   2014-05-31
123           2          2014-07-10     2014-11-10
324           0          2014-05-09     2014-11-12
```

I do realize that right now the two projects for program 123 will show for both lines - we will be looking for a way to associate them with the right ones but do not have that yet.

We added the override date requirement so that a report of current programs would not show both the '123' lines but only the one that is current (the second one).

My current SELECT is like this (sorry, I can't get this to show easier it is really long):

```
SELECT milestones.*,  newtbl.prjcnt, exceptions.overEnd  
FROM milestones 
LEFT JOIN ((
     SELECT prgGuid, count( prgGuid ) AS prjcnt 
     FROM projects 
     GROUP BY prgGuid 
    ) AS newtbl ) 
ON milestones.prgId = newtbl.prgId 
LEFT JOIN exceptions 
ON (milestones.prgId = exceptions.prgId 
AND milestones.startDate = exceptions.startDate) 
WHERE <(milestones.startDate > '2013-00-00') 
AND (milestones.startDate <= CURDATE() AND milestones.endDate >= CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY milestones.endDate, milestones.startDate DESC
```

Now what I want is to change this to only grab programs, project counts, start and end dates, and the override end date for programs where the start date is anything from 2013 to the current date and that have not ended yet. Now....if a program has an override end date and that end date is current (>= the current date) it should be included but if the override date is NULL or <= the current date, I do not want to include it.

What I want to have returned is:

```
prgId       prjCnt       startDate       endDate     overEnd
123           2          2014-07-10      2014-11-10
324           0          2014-05-09      2014-11-12
```

The first line before has expired so shouldn't show.

I've tried a few things but I either end up with no results or I get everything that I am currently getting.

Can someone help me figure out what the SELECT should be?

Comment: Instead of trying to put all your end date override conditions into a join, just outer join to your exception table (without extra conditions) and use a CASE statement in your SELECT clause to apply the rules you want to the output override date column.

Comment: I've never done that do you by chance have an example?

Comment: Taking a closer look, it is clear that you don't actually need a CASE in your select.  It's just a matter of fixing up your WHERE clause.  See my full answer below.

Answer (score 1):

So if I follow you, your DDL might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MILESTONES
    (`prgId` int, `startDate` varchar(10), `endDate` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO MILESTONES
    (`prgId`, `startDate`, `endDate`)
VALUES
    (123, '2014-03-09', '2014-11-10'),
    (123, '2014-07-10', '2014-11-10'),
    (324, '2014-05-09', '2014-11-12')
;

CREATE TABLE EXCEPTIONS
    (`prgId` int, `startDate` varchar(10), `overEnd` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO EXCEPTIONS
    (`prgId`, `startDate`, `overEnd`)
VALUES
    (123, '2014-03-09', '2014-05-31')
;

CREATE TABLE PROJECTS
    (`prgId` int, `cust` int)
;

INSERT INTO PROJECTS
    (`prgId`, `cust`)
VALUES
    (123, 12121),
    (123, 4323)
;
```

And your current query which isn't working is this (note I've corrected what I presume are typos in your query from your question):

```
SELECT milestones.*,  newtbl.prjcnt, exceptions.overEnd  
FROM milestones 
LEFT JOIN ((
     SELECT prgId, count( prgId ) AS prjcnt 
     FROM projects 
     GROUP BY prgId 
    ) AS newtbl ) 
ON milestones.prgId = newtbl.prgId 
LEFT JOIN exceptions 
ON (milestones.prgId = exceptions.prgId 
AND milestones.startDate = exceptions.startDate) 
WHERE (milestones.startDate > '2013-00-00') 
AND (milestones.startDate <= CURDATE() AND milestones.endDate >= CURDATE()) 
ORDER BY milestones.endDate, milestones.startDate DESC
```

**A working solution looks like this:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  M.prgId as PRGID
, ( SELECT COUNT(X.prgID)
    FROM PROJECTS X
    WHERE X.prgID = M.prgID ) as PRJCNT
, M.startDate as STARTDATE
, M.endDate as ENDDATE
, COALESCE(E.overEnd,'') as OVEREND
FROM MILESTONES M
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECTS P
    ON M.prgId = P.prgId
  LEFT JOIN EXCEPTIONS E
    ON M.prgId = E.prgId
   AND M.startDate = E.startDate
WHERE M.startDate > '2013-01-01'
  AND M.startDate <= CURDATE()
  AND M.endDate >= CURDATE()
  AND ( E.overEnd IS NULL
     OR E.overEnd > CURDATE() )
```

You can see it in action here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/533d9/28).

Note that the solution relies on the COALESCE function for clean output and more of your business rules being put in place in the WHERE clause.

Comment: thank you so much. I will try that. I had looked at the CASE and didn't think it would work either. I haven't used the COALESCE before so will also look into that.

Comment: thank you! it worked very well. I greatly appreciate the help.